# Using SignInWithEmailAndPassword in firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

How to use signInWithEmailAndPassword of firebase in expo? Can anyone tell me what to write?

Comment: Hi does my answer help, if yes then acknowledge it, if not then we can solve further ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `signInWithEmailAndPassword` with expo the same as we use in the regular react app. You can check [**Sign in a user with an email address and password**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth#sign_in_a_user_with_an_email_address_and_password) for how it is used in Firebase V9.

But if you need React Native support for all Firebase services on both Android and iOS apps.
Then you can use [**React Native Firebase**](https://rnfirebase.io/) also there you can find [**Email/Password sign-in**](https://rnfirebase.io/auth/usage#emailpassword-sign-in) with `signInWithEmailAndPassword` :

```
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';

auth()
  .signInWithEmailAndPassword('jane.doe@example.com', 'SuperSecretPassword!')
  .then(() => {
    console.log('User signed in!');
  })
  .catch(error => {
    if (error.code === 'auth/user-not-found') {
      console.log('There no user exist with that email');
    }

    if (error.code === 'auth/invalid-email') {
      console.log('That email address is invalid!');
    }
    console.error(error);
  });
```